# How to generate a report of missing OS patches for Azure VMs using Azure native services(Azure Log analytics/automation account)?

Tags: azure, patch, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation, azure-log-analytics

How to generate a report of missing OS patches for the Azure VMs using Azure native services like Azure Log analytics/automation account?

I need to generate a report with Below details.

```
Subscription name or ID
Resource Group name or ID
VM name
OS Type (Windows/Linux)
OS Version (Win2012, 2016, Linux RedHat, Ubuntu...)
VMs IP address
No. of missing Critical and Security OS patches
Date of information gathering
```

Could you please anyone help me with this?

Comment: How about this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-tutorial-update-management